# Endemic plant families on islands?

Tags: botany, taxonomy

Endemism on islands is quite a common phenomenon, at least at the level of species or genera. Old continental fragments like Madagascar or New Caledonia may even harbour endemic families which went extinct on the continents. I also know of the odd example of Lactoridaceae that comprise only one species which is endemic to the Juan Fernandez Islands.

Do you know other instances of endemic **families** on islands? What about Hawai'i, the Canaries or Galapagos?

Comment: This link (http://lntreasures.com/index.html ) might help you...it doesn't mention particularly about islands...but still I think it's a great site ( if you already don't know about it) for ecologists, like you...

Comment: That link is awesome (I didn't know it yet)! +1